# Unable to Mount... EXT4: First Meta block group too large

Tags: linux, mount, ext4, resize2fs

```
EXT4-fs (dm-46): first meta block group too large: 1152 (group descriptor block count 1096)
```

I have a filesystem, which is ext4, on a machine with 4.17.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64. The logical volume is 8.56 TiB.

This filesystem has been resized many times since it was first created.

It passes e2fsck:

```
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/vg_areca/lv_MYLVNAME: clean, 59060/574488576 files, 2294844696/2297954304 blocks
```

After the last "resize2fs", I started receiving this error via "dmesg". I was running kernel 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64 and after some googling, found that the current version of [linux corrected a bug](https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7018898) that produced this error. However, after updating the kernel, I am still getting the error.

My thoughts are that my multiple resizes has surfaced an issue, but I'm not sure how to address it.

[debugfs output](https://pastebin.com/EN1xyBAM) (minus 70k entries for Group 70127: (Blocks 2297921536-2297954303) [INODE_UNINIT, ITABLE_ZEROED]") is below

Answer (score 0):

I think you are the reporter of [this kernel bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200371). Since I ran into the same problem, I followed the advice from Theodore Tso in a comment there:

> In any case, the file system really is corrupted, although the good news is that should be a relatively simple thing to fix; you just need to upgrade to a non-prehistoric version of e2fsprogs.

I was using `e2fsprogs` 1.42.9 from CentOS. Building 1.44.4 locally via

```
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/tytso/e2fsprogs/v1.44.4/e2fsprogs-1.44.4.tar.xz
tar xfv e2fsprogs-1.44.4.tar.xz
cd e2fsprogs-1.44.4
./configure
make
```

and then using

```
./e2fsck/e2fsck <blockdevice>
```

allowed me to repair the filesystem.